# Time complexity T(n) for an algorithm that depends on 2 inputs

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, analysis

Normally when analyzing the running time of an algorithm i am dealing with a single input that affects the running time. I'm trying to understand how to represent T(n) when there are 2 or more inputs that affect the running time.

For example in linear search in the worse case:

```
function LinearSearch(arr, N, x)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)        ---> C1*N + C2
        if arr[i] = x              ---> C3*N
            return true            

    return false                   ---> C4
```

T(n) = (C1 + C3)*N + (C2 + C4)
= CN + C

so T(n) is linear with respect to N.

Now say there was an another algorithm that took in inputs X and Y and i did a similar analysis and found the cost in the worst case to be:

T(n) = CX + C

and the best case to be:

T(n) = CY + C

My question is, is it correct to represent the running time like this? Given that there are two different inputs that affect the running time in different cases.

I've not managed to find much information online or in text books but i've been thinking about whether the n in T(n) represents all the inputs, or could it be represented like so:

T(X) = CX + C

T(Y) = CY + C

I've also seen an algorithm in a research paper described similarly to:

T(n, m) = some expression

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: An example of an algorithm where the time complexity depends on two inputs could be radix sort.

I understand that radix sort is often represented as O(n*k) where n is the number of elements to be sorted and k is the number of digits of the max value.

Ignoring the the exact details of T(n), how might this be represented?

Comment: `O(n*k)` is linear in both `x` and `k` (obviously), it's ok to say `O(n)` with the implication that `k` is fixed (or vice versa).  After all, most real-world algorithms have many parameters; its textbooks that only depend on one

Comment: "correct" in this case is really a matter of convention in this case, as its just notation.  I would say any of `O(n*k)`, `O(k)`, `O(x)` are correct with an understanding of assumptions therein

Comment: So in the above example of the best case being CY + C, if i was asked the best case in terms of T(X), would it be constant as the running time in respect to X is not affected by Y (in the best case)?

Comment: well no.  If the question is "best case in terms of X", you would expect to see the running time with respect to X.

Comment: The problem i'm having though is if i work out the best case, such as CY + C, and they ask for in terms of X, i don't understand what that would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the complexity of the algorithm depends on a single parameter and you want to call that parameter `X`, the time complexity will also be dependent on `X` and not on `n` (what is `n`?): e.g. `T(X) = X^2`.

If the complexity of the algorithm depends on parameters `n1`, `n2`, ..., `nk` (and the parameters are mutually independent), then the time complexity will be a function in `k` parameters, `T(n1, ..., nk)`.

For example, an algorithm that takes two strings of lengths `x` and `y` and prints them would have time complexity `T(x,y) = O(x + y)`.